# How can I create and send JSON file without saving it to disk?

Tags: java, file, jackson

Before sending JSON file to user (via Telegram Bot) I save it to disk. Can I just create and send JSON file to user without saving it to disk?

```
private static final String PATH = "./library/";

    public static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public void toJSON(Task task) throws IOException {
        String packageName = taskService.getId(task);
        String fileName = packageName + ".json";
        String pathName = LIBRARY_PATH + fileName;
        Path path = Paths.get(pathName);
        if (!Files.exists(path)) {
            Files.createDirectories(path.getParent());
            Files.createFile(path);
        }
        objectMapper.writeValue(new File(pathName), googlePlayGame);
    }
```

Comment: Assuming this code is using Jackson (I optimistically tagged it as such), `objectMapper.writeValueAsString()` should give you the JSON as a `String`. There's also `writeValueAsBytes()` if you need raw bytes.

Comment: writeValueAsBytes with ByteArrayInputStream works the way I wanted, thanks! Yes, it's Jackson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`objectMapper.writeValueAsString()` gives you the JSON as a String. There's also `objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes()` if you need raw bytes.